# localhost htaccess url rewrite problem

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

I have already configured my apache(mod_rewrite,alias,allowOverride), and I am trying to rewrite

```
http://localhost/b33m/view_blog_details.php?post_id=4
```

To

```
http://localhost/b33m/blogs/4
```

so that user can simply type in the second url and it would work. But I am getting a 404 not found error.

I am using WAMP on XP, and my `.htaccess` is in `www->b33m`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^b33m/blogs/([^/]*)$ /b33m/view_blog_details.php?post_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: stupid question but did you activate mod_rewrite on wamp? I know I had to do this the first time I used mod_rerwrite on wamp

Comment: Yes, as I said already, those are already configured properly...I checked in the wamp->apache->apache modules menu

Comment: are you working directly in the www folder or in a submap? if it's in a submap you might need to add a rewritebase

Comment: I am in the b33m sub directory... could you please explain "rewritebase"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

EDIT: I updated the code which hopefully will work better

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /b33m
RewriteRule ^blogs/([0-9]+)$ /view_blog_details.php?post_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It works if I have my .htaccess in my www folder, but then all my images and such which are at a relative path get broken... and I don't have access to the www(public_html) folder in the server, so I need to place the .htaccess in the b33m subdirectory, and if I do that, I get the 404 page

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blogs/(\d+)$ view_blog_details.php?post_id=$1 [L]
```

Note the `/` in the beginning of each URL have been omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you expect an id I'd rather use:

Moreover shouldn't you put a trailing slash?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/b33m/blogs/(\d+)$ /b33m/view_blog_details.php?post_id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your hosts file:

```
www.localhost.com  127.0.0.1
```

.htaccess sometimes doesn't like localhost

Comment: I don't know about this, I've been able to get it working in wamp without doing this

Comment: lol, I'm not the one with the question :) I'm just another person trying to help